# Adding titles to highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I'm wondering is it possible to add titles as shown in the image below in the red square. Any demo will be appreciated!

[Highcart with titles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLFpI.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should be able to achieve the wanted effect by using the below config with dummy series to render the second y-axis:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },

  xAxis: [{
    title: {
      align: 'high',
      rotation: 0,
      y: -20,
      x: 45,
      text: 'test',
      style: {
        "color": "#333333",
        "fontSize": "18px"
      }
    }
  }, {
    offset: 150,
    tickLength: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    categories: ['26-35', '16-25', '36-45', '46-55', '56-65', '66-75', '75+'],
    title: {
      align: 'high',
      rotation: 0,
      y: -20,
      x: 45,
      text: 'test',
      style: {
        "color": "#333333",
        "fontSize": "18px"
      }
    },
  }],

  series: [{
    // dummy series
    type: 'column',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133],
    xAxis: 1,
    showInLegend: false,
    color: 'transparent',
    enableMouseTracking: false
  }, {
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133],
    name: 'main series'
  }]
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3qu4Lv19/

API to used features:

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.title.style
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.offset
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.enableMouseTracking

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried the way you showed me, works like a charm! Thank you!