# How to align xAxis titles to the left and right

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem to align titles on xAxis to the left and right like on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QmCm.jpg). I've tried by adding html tags and inline styles to achieve this, but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
xAxis: [{
  type: 'category',
  labels: {
    step: 1,
  },
  scrollbar: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  min: 0,
  categories: [],
  title: {
    align: 'high',
    rotation: 0,
    y: -20,
    x: 60,
    text: subtitleOne,
    style: {
      "fontSize": "14px",
      "fontWeight": "bold",
      "textAlign": "left"
    }
  }
}, {
    offset: 0,
    tickLength: 0,
    lineWidth: 0,
    title: {
      align: 'high',
      rotation: 0,
      y: -20,
      x: 45,
      text: subtitleTwo,
      style: {
        "fontSize": "14px",
        "fontWeight": "bold"
      }
    }
  }]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: May I ask what is the difference in your current requirement and the previous one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191308/adding-titles-to-highcharts - I think that the config which I shared in this question could be used in your current one. If you have some troubles with implementing it - please reproduce your code on some online editor which I could work on.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I achieved my goal by adding useHTML property and formatter with HTML tags and inline styles.